# Create a rockspec for windows

Tags: lua, luarocks

I'm bit confused from the LuaRocks documentation. I'm creating a rockspec that will copy library dll files to clibs and a file apender to lua/logging folder. 
here what I have so far

```
package = "lualoggingapender"
version = "1.0-1"
source = {
    url = "",
}
description = {
   summary = "An example for the LuaRocks tutorial.",
   detailed = [[
      This is an example for the LuaRocks tutorial.
      Here we would put a detailed, typically
      paragraph-long description.
   ]],
   homepage = "http://...", -- We don't have one yet
   license = "MIT/X11" -- or whatever you like
}
dependencies = {
   "lua ~> 5.1"
   -- If you depend on other rocks, add them here
}
build = {
  type = "make",
  install_variables = {
    LUA_LIBDIR = "$(LIBDIR)",
    LUA_DIR = "$(LUADIR)",
    BIN_DIR = "$(BINDIR)"
  },
  platforms = {
    win32 = {
      type = "make",
      build_variables = {
        LUA_DIR = "$(LUA_LIBDIR)\\lib/lib.dll",
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is this how should I do it ??

my config file is

```
local LFW_ROOT = config.LFW_ROOT
rocks_servers = {
   [[http://luarocks.org/repositories/rocks]]
}
rocks_trees = {
   { root = LFW_ROOT, rocks_dir = LFW_ROOT..[[\rocks]],
     bin_dir = LFW_ROOT, lua_dir = LFW_ROOT..[[\lua]],
     lib_dir = LFW_ROOT..[[\clibs]] }
}
variables.WRAPPER = LFW_ROOT..[[\rclauncher.obj]]
```

when I'm trying to run it i get the following error

```
'nmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Error: Build error: Failed building.
```

And when I run it in VS2013 command line I get the following error

```
NMAKE : fatal error U1052: file 'Makefile.win' not found
Stop.

Error: Build error: Failed building.
```

One final thing should i use make or buildin and what is the difference

**Update**: I was able to make the lua module to be copied and build but I'm still having issue with installing lib it say: **Failing copying FileName** here is my final code look like

```
package = "lualoggingapender"
version = "1.0-1"
source = {
    url = "",
    dir = "lib",
    dir = "logging"
}
description = {
   summary = "An example for the LuaRocks tutorial.",
   detailed = [[
      This is an example for the LuaRocks tutorial.
      Here we would put a detailed, typically
      paragraph-long description.
   ]],
   homepage = "http://...", -- We don't have one yet
   license = "MIT/X11" -- or whatever you like
}
dependencies = {
   "lua ~> 5.1",
   -- If you depend on other rocks, add them here
}

build = {
  type = "builtin",
  install_variables = {
    LUA_LIBDIR = "$(LIBDIR)",
    LUA_DIR = "$(LUADIR)",
    BIN_DIR = "$(BINDIR)"
  },
  platforms = {
    win32 = {
     type = "builtin",
      modules = {
      ["logging.windows"] = "windows.lua",
      },
      install = {
        lib = {
        winEvntLog ="lib/winEvntLog.dll",
        msgLog = "lib/msgLog.dll",
        },
      },
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you write a makefile? build.type="make" requires writing a makefile. You can avoid that by using build.type="builtin". What are the source files for your project? (.lua and .c files)

Comment: It works for the lua file I was able to move the file to lobbing folder. But when I use Install = { lib = { lib = "lib.dll"}} it return back with an error saying failed copying lib.dll

Comment: @HishamHM I'm not sure I'm doing it right the way I'm trying to copy this DLL files, cause I found out the build.Install.lib work only with external library that was built. I tried copy_directories but it seems it is not working, the 2 dll file are in a folder called lib, could you please provide me with a sample code that could solve it judging from my previous updated code. Thanks

Comment: @HishamHM, My luarocks version was installed by luaforwindows is 2.0.2 and I'm assuming it is old to support copy_directories. I tired to update the luarocks, using the luarocks command I got error, I have raise it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26019492/luarocks-stop-working-after-updating-from-2-0-2-to-2-2-0-for-windows  any Idea how to fix it?