# Luarocks stop working after updating from 2.0.2 to 2.2.0 for windows

Tags: lua, luarocks

I used LuaForWindows to install lua that comes with LuaRocks 2.0.2, when I type luarocks install luarocks in the command line it install the latest 2.2.0 luarocks but when I try to use luarocks to install other rocks it will come back with an error

```
Site-local luarocks/site_config.lua file not found. Incomplete installation?
'uname' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'uname' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
C:/Program Files (x86)/Lua/5.1/lua: C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\lua/luarocks\
cfg.lua:80: attempt to index local 'proc' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\lua/luarocks\cfg.lua:80: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'require'
        ...\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\lua/luarocks\loader.lua:17: in main chun
k
        [C]: ?
        [C]: ?
```

is there any extra step I'm missing to make it work 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`luarocks install luarocks` is only supported from 2.1.0 onwards (and mostly tested on Unix).

To upgrade from older versions on Windows, please use the [supplied .zip file for Windows from the LuaRocks website](http://luarocks.org/releases/).

Comment: I still get an error: bad argument #1 to 'require' (string expected, got table) when I call luarocks. Here what were my steps. first I installed luaforwindows than I downloaded the 2.2.0 win32 zip file in command line I run Install /L /P <path> than I copied luarocks folder and paste it into the luarocks folder ./lua/5.1/lua where the pervious luarocks was, I copied the config that generated from installation to ./lua/5.1. where you think I'm doing wrong, or there is another way to do it

Comment: Hisham I was able to upgrade luarocks, I install luaforwindows without a rock and i did use the zip file and copy luarocks folder plus i did copy the other luarocks_... files into ./lua/5.1 folder

Comment: Nice to know you found a way to do it! If you have any further questions on running LuaRocks on Windows, the best way to get help is the luarocks-developers mailing list!